# Javascript drag and drop - setDragimage() method takes screenshots of the overflow image

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, typescript

When I use the setDragimage() method for dragging, the overflow image on the element is taken as a screenshot.

Working example: https://codepen.io/Giridhar-T/pen/rNoBQOL

```
[https://codepen.io/Giridhar-T/pen/rNoBQOL][1]
```

In the above example, the skating image is overlapped with the drag element instead of the original background element.

Can someone help how to avoid overflow images while dragging?

I purposefully added position absolute to recreate this issue, because in my application facing an issue with the bottom navigation icon.

Comment: Remove the CSS `position: absolute` in the img style

Comment: yeah, I purposefully added position absolute to recreate this issue, because in my application facing an issue with the bottom navigation icon.